# Change an input's colour to its value

Tags: jquery

I have a class of inputs containing hex values for colour, without the `#`.

I want to set each input's background color to its value. I tried this, but it doesn't change the colour:

```
$(".colourPick").css('background', '#' + $(this).val());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/7GZes/)

```
$(".colourPick").each (function () {
   $(this).css('background-color', '#' + $(this).val());
});
```